# How to get uniform tabs/spaces in other programs (like Less)

Tags: vim-windows

How does one get uniform tabs/spaces to display properly in other programs (like Less)?

For example, say I am modifying my .vimrc in Vim and I've created two columns on the same line (one for rule and one for comment).

In Vim the comments all line up:

```
set textwidth=80        " set line length
set tabstop=4           " how many cols a tab counts for
set expandtab           " insert spaces for <tab>
set softtabstop=4       " tabs are 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4        " indent/outdent by 4 cols
```

Now for the sake of example, say I open it again in Less. The output would be something like:

```
set textwidth=80        " set line length
set tabstop=4             " how many cols a tab counts for
set expandtab             " insert spaces for <tab>
set softtabstop=4          " tabs are 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4        " indent/outdent by 4 cols
```

Am I unknowingly mixing a combination of tabs and spaces? Or does it have to do with my tab settings?

Comment: How did you align your comments? Did you manually do it pressing `<tab>` and `<space>` to align these comments? Did you use something like [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) or [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align)?

Comment: No it was all manual alignment with `<tab>` and possibly `<space>`

Comment: A "standard" tabstop setting is 8. If you use something else, you risk these sorts of display problems. You can `:set list` to see the tabs in Vim. You can set `tabstop` to 8 and `softtabstop` and `shiftwidth` to 4 and get the editing behavior you want while preserving compatibility with other programs such as `less`.

Comment: The other way: [set tab width for less output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147443/70524)

Answer (score 3):

You always want to use spaces for alignments. Vim's `<tab>` will insert spaces or real tabs depending on the setting of `'expandtab'`. You can see the value of `'expandtab'` via `:set expandtab?`.

Personally I would suggest you use an some type of aligning plugin to avoid doing this manually. Both [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) and [vim-easy-align](http://vim-easy-align) are good choices. Example of using tabular:

```
:Tabularize/"/
```

Comment: _You always want to use spaces for alignments._ - A more complete answer would begin with a phrase more or less like this: "The world of programmers is divided in two big tribes: tab lovers, and tab haters.  They don't go along very well with each other". ;)

Comment: I agree there are different views on indention, but until [variable tab stops](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/eNOQO06iRZQ) or [Elastic Tab stops](http://nickgravgaard.com/elastic-tabstops/) become a thing not just for Vim, but all text editors everywhere. I think the only real option is spaces for alignments. I mean its pretty simple you can mix tab indent + spaces for alignment or spaces everywhere. This will work on all editors no matter the settings or line lengths. But tabs for alignment!? Whoa! Slow down! You are going to get in trouble before you know it.